# How to display JSON data comes from the Multiple file in NODEJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm stuck in this problem from last 3 days,
 I'm creating a simple application which shows languages and their topics and latest version of that particular Language in NODEJS.
 So I created 3 separate JSON file 1.For Languages 2. For their topics 3.For latest version.
 
 I created api for these 3 files and a simple HTML page in which I can show that data so here is the code.
Can someone guide me how can I do that.....

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()


var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var Languages = require('./public/Languages.json')
var Languages = require('./public/LVersion.json')
var Languages = require('./public/subtopics.json')


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


// Defining HTML file
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html')
})
// Send Responce to user
app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    let v1 = String(req.body.langu)
    res.send(v1+' is your Data')

})


var url1 = 'http://localhost:3000/api/languages'
var url2 = 'http://localhost:3000/api/Lversion'
var url3 = 'http://localhost:3000/api/subtopicp'


//Api for getting Languages
app.get('/api/languages',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/languages.json')
})

//Api for getting Latest Version
app.get('/api/latestv',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/Lversion.json')
})

//Api for getting Sub Topics
app.get('/api/subtopicp',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/subtopics.json')
})
//Read and Parse Languages
let lan = fs.readFileSync('./public/Languages.json')
let lang = JSON.parse(lan)
//Read and parse Latest Version
let LV = fs.readFileSync('./public/LVersion.json')
let LVer = JSON.parse(LV)
//Read and parse subtopics
let subt = fs.readFileSync('./public/subtopics.json')
let subtopic = JSON.parse(subt)




var port = 3000
app.listen(port,(req,res)=>{
    console.log('App is Listen on localhost: ' +port )
})
```

Here is the HTML code. I'm not concentrated on the UI, I just want to show data in the browser.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Getting Data From json</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Here You Get Latest Technologes , Subtopics and Latest Versions</h1>
    <form method="POST">

        <h3>OR Select</h3>

        <!-- Drop Down -->
        <select id="cars" name="Langu">
            <option value="C">C</option>
            <option value="CPlusPLus">C++</option>
            <option value="JAVA">JAVA</option>
            <option value="NODE">NODE</option>
          </select>
          <br><br>


        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Json Files
Languages.json

```
{
    "Lan": [ "C", "C++",  "Java","Python"]
}
```

LVersion.json

```
{
    "C":{
        "LV" : "C 18"
     },
     "java":{
         "LV": "Java SE 13.0.1"
     },
     "Python":{
        "LV": "Python 3.8"
    }

}
```

SubTopics.json

```
{
        "C": {
            "topics": [
                "Data Types",
                "XML",
                "Variables",
                "Loops",
                "And More"
                    ]
        },
        "C++" : {
            "topics": [
                "Constants",
                "Oprators",
                "Input/Output",
                "Arrays",
                "Classes",
                "Special Members"
            ]
        },
        "Java" : {
            "topics": [
                "Constants",
                "Oprators",
                "Input/Output",
                "Arrays",
                "Classes",
                "Special Members"
            ]
        },
        "Python" : {
            "topics": [
                "Exceptions",
                "Lists",
                "Functions",
                "Modules",
                "Classes",
                "Files I/O"
            ]
        }


    }
```

Here I give the all code and information which I can give.
GitHub link of this project if you want full source and some solution:
[Link](https://github.com/kirtanth/NodeWithJsonEx)
Thank You.

Comment: show us your frontend js code too

Comment: This is the only code i write. i think remaining part is like have to write code for getting data from api which i created and that only i don't know

Comment: if you have any idea how to do that just guide me or refer some link so from that i can complete my remaining  project

Comment: jquery getjson as starter

Answer (score 1):

So what you need now is to fetch data from your API in your front-end.
You just need to setup a way to perform HTTP Requests. In your body, add a `<script>` tag as last element, and insert in it your logic to fetch data from your API.

There are a tons of libraries and ways to get data from the web, like axios or jQuery's methods. Since yours is a pretty simple project, you can just use the native ones: use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), which has Promise support, to fetch data and add them to the DOM.

If you plan to support older browsers, you should look at [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Anyway: looking at your Node.js code, you are overwriting variable Languages with tre different requires. By doing this, you are not merging all the JSON Objects. If you want to use one object to contain them all, use `Object.assign`.